# Does omitting non-capturing groups ?: have a negative effect on RegExp.prototype.test()?

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

I am currently testing a string to be in a specific mail format.

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9](([A-Za-z0-9]|\.(?!\.))*[A-Za-z0-9]+)?@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$/.test(email)
```

Now I have some parenthesis which could be marked as non-capturing groups like this:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9](?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9]|\.(?!\.))*[A-Za-z0-9]+)?@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$/.test(email)
```

But I don't see any difference between the results. Tests only checks, so it should be irrelevant, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching between capturing and noncapturing groups in test is relevant only if you use backreferences (`\1` `\2`). As you don't, the change has no effect.